# iOS: DrawRect repaint

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I am new to iOS programming and hope you can help me with a problem :-)

In my app I am drawing a circle using the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` function.
Everything works good! Now we come to my problem:

When I press a button on the app, another circle should be painted and the old one should be modified (change color or radius or something). How to do it?

How to repaint the view?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please be aware that `IOS` is not the same as `iOS` there is a different and it isn't just one is uppercase and the other is not. I have edited your question title accordingly. I have also removed the `Apple` tag as this has nothing to actually do with Apple themselves and I removed the `xcode` tag because this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`. Happy coding

Comment: Sorry :-X I will do my very best to be more careful in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repaint a view with this code:

```
[yourview setNeedsDisplay];
```

This will force `drawRect` to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

Add another circle to your main view

```
[self.view addSubview:anotherView]
```